# Set Statement returning Null

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, visual-studio-2013

I am having an issue getting the value of a property to commit to the database.  I have logic in my get statement that returns a value based on the value's from two other properties.  The logic works correctly and displays the correct values in My Web Page, however the value for Rating Field is always set as Null in the database.  My code below - if someone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PSA.Models
{
    public class Issue
    {
        public virtual int IssueID { get; set; }
        public virtual int ProbableClassificationId { get; set; }
        public virtual ProbableClassification ProbableClassification { get; set; }
        public virtual int SeverityClassificationId { get; set; }
        public virtual SeverityClassification SeverityClassification { get; set; }
        string ratingstatus;
        public virtual string Rating 
        {
            get 
            {
                if (ProbableClassification != null && SeverityClassification != null)
                {
                    if (SeverityClassification.Severity == "Minor")
                    {
                        ratingstatus = "Low";
                    }
                    if (ProbableClassification.Probability == "Not Likely" && SeverityClassification.Severity == "Medium")
                    {
                        ratingstatus = "Low";
                    }
                    if (ProbableClassification.Probability == "Likely" && SeverityClassification.Severity == "Medium")
                    {
                        ratingstatus = "Medium";
                    }
                    if (ProbableClassification.Probability == "Definitely" && SeverityClassification.Severity == "Medium")
                    {
                        ratingstatus = "Medium";
                    }
                    if (ProbableClassification.Probability == "Not Likely" && SeverityClassification.Severity == "Major")
                    {
                        ratingstatus = "Low";
                    }
                    if (ProbableClassification.Probability == "Likely" && SeverityClassification.Severity == "Major")
                    {
                        ratingstatus = "High";
                    }
                    if (ProbableClassification.Probability == "Definitely" && SeverityClassification.Severity == "Major")
                    {
                        ratingstatus = "Crtical";
                    }

                }
            return ratingstatus;
            }
            set
            {
                ratingstatus = value;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you even want to save that value to the database? I would hesitate to add a column to a database which is completely redundant, i.e. which can be computed using other columns.

Comment: As I understand your code, the return value depends on ProbableClassification and SeverityClassification. AFAIK, EF loads the values of such properties not in all circumstances, e.g. if you specify matching includes. This leads to your property behaving differently based on how the object was loaded which is highly error prone. I also can't see a reason why you would want to store a value that you can derive from other properties. Therefore, I'd suggest not to store the value and to change the design in a way that guarantees that the other properties are loaded when retrieving the value.

Comment: Thanks Guys, the reason for storing in the database is that I don't want to have to write the code to derive the value multiple times.  If I store it in the database I will be able to write reports and use the data whenever I want to.